# Adjusting mat-table on xs screen size using flex box css in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have implemented a simple angular material table using flexbox css.

### In the desktop my table view is as shown below.

[image]

### In md screen size the view is

[image]

### In xs screen size its view is

[image]

When i see the table in XS screen view ,the spacing between the table columns is not properly adjusted..

Is there a way out where i can add a horizontal scroll to space the table columns properly by specifying a min width to my table and adding a horizontal scroll when in XS and SM screen sizes.

### Below shown is my .html file

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

### Below is my .css file

```
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin:10px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

mat-header-cell, mat-header-row, .mat-header-cell-def{
    background:#f2f4f7;
    min-height:15px;
    font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    color: #1a084c;
    margin-bottom:5px;
     top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
}

mat-row{
    min-height:20px;
    font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color: #1a084c;
    }
mat-cell{
    height:20px;
    font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px; 
    color: #1a084c;
}
```

### Below is my .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {ShowmenuService} from '../showmenu.service';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator} from '@angular/material';
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-space-admin',
  templateUrl: './space-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./space-admin.component.css']
})
export class SpaceAdminComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public showmenu:ShowmenuService, private _activateroute: ActivatedRoute, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showmenu.show();
    this.showmenu.show1();
      }
  displayedColumns = ['select','position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  /**
   * Set the paginator after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized paginator.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

### modified table in xs view

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To adjust the spacing between the columns, set min width on mat-cell and use media queries.

For example for small screens:

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 736px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    mat-header-row, mat-row {
     width: 200%;  //you can also set it in px,em, etc...
    }

  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ejrbj)

Comment: its working for me as i wished it to be ... but when i scroll right to see the remaining columns , i don't find the separation between the rows , as in the starting columns.. i have added the screen shot in  my question ... please have a look.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the problem here ..?

Comment: why are the rows not separated as in the start?

Comment: yes exactly i got it as per my requirement ... thanks a lot again..thanks for the help..