# Unable to hide the navigation bar in login page when redirecting from home page to login page

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to implement a sample app in **Angular** using **Angular Material** and **Angular Flex Layout**.

I have implemented a navigation bar which is hidden in login page and visible in all pages in the appllication.

I have created a **service** with the name **showmenu.service.ts** where I have declared two variable and assigned them as boolean..

I am able to hide the navigation bar in my login page as start my application. But as I login in to the application, I am getting the following error in my console as shown below.

[image]

I am unable to find out the problem..And also when I am trying to logout I am again getting the Navigation bar in my login page as shown below.

[image]

[image]

can anybody help me out with this issue....?

Please access my sample app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: You stackblitz is not working (Import error, can't find file: environments/environment.ts)

Comment: Please provide a working stackblitz

Comment: Yes please make working stackblitz example.

Comment: Please provide working code

Comment: Can you please check this out......... https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login-blrcbg?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: @VivekDoshi. .......... can you please check this link ...... https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login-blrcbg?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: still i can see `Can't find package:hammerjs`

Comment: @RameshRajendran.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login-blrcbg?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts... please check this...!

Comment: Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171213/discussion-between-heena-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Comment: @VivekDoshi... Hi can you check this link once again please..........https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login-bm7t1c?file=app%2Fshowmenu.service.ts

Comment: @VivekDoshi....... can you please help me out with this issue........https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387896/unable-to-hide-the-navigation-bar-in-login-page-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `[hidden]` instead if `*ngIf`. I had this same problem some months ago and it resolved to me. **So it should solve your error.**

So use this `[hidden]="showmenu.visible1"`  instead of `*ngIf="showmenu.visible1"`

---

And kindly check [angular 2 - how to hide nav bar in some components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118592/angular-2-how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-components) how it is works for show/hide menus by using service and compare with your code...