# Unable to hide the navigation bar in login page in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to implement a sample app in **Angular** using **Angular** **Material** and **Angular** **Flex** **Layout**.

I have implemented a navigation bar which i want to hide in login page and visible in all pages in the application.

I have created a service with the name **showmenu.service.ts** where I have declared a variable and assigned as boolean value.  Also defined two functions **show()** and **hide()**

I am not getting any error, but I am unable to hide the navigation bar in my login page .

[image]

Please access my sample code here ..https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login-bm7t1c?file=app%2Fshowmenu.service.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made lot of changes to resolve it.

Please take a look at this

### [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-login-eqquk9?file=app/app.component.ts)

---

The changes are,

you need a click event for logout button instead of direct navigation

```
(click)="logout()"
```

and the logout method should be like below (to hide the menu and do navigation here).

```
logout()
  {
    this.showmenu.hide();
    this._router.navigate(['myform']);
  }
```

also I don't know why `[hidden]` is not working for you. So i just use the visible property in `fxShow` to solve your problem.

```
 fxShow="{{!showmenu.visible}}"
```

*Finally we did it* :)

Comment: awesome sir................hats off to you ............ i was just searching different ways out to hide nav bar........

Comment: You are just fantastic

Comment: But as i login initially the navigation bar is not visible ,but if i resize then it come up......Y is this happening..?

Comment: What you mean by resize

Comment: @Heena But it's working fine in the demo :(  https://sample-login-eqquk9.stackblitz.io/myform

Comment: No ..when i first login then i dont find the nav bar in home page ..when i restore window then the nav bar is visible...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171299/discussion-between-heena-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Comment: .............please check this out ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598376/unable-to-run-angular-js-app-in-apache-tomcat