# Unable to run angular JS app in apache tomcat

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, bootstrap-4, eclipse-oxygen

I have created a Dynamic web project in eclipse IDE. And converted it to angular JS project. I have successfully installed and configured Apache Tomcat 9.0 and I am able to access tomcat on localhost:8080

### Below shown is my project directory structure...

[image]

When I am trying to run the application on apache server,I am getting error as shown below.........

[image]

### Below is my code.

`controller.js`:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [" "]);
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Angular JS -->  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>



<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Controller.js -->
<script src="controller.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-view></div>

<h6>Sample Angular JS App</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The url should be - http://localhost:8088/DemoJscript/index.html

Comment: even that url is not working....!

Comment: Please check if the context-root(DemoJscript) is correct and move the index.html and controller.js to WebContent folder.

Comment: file:///D:/oxygen/DemoJscript/WebContent/index.html............ on this url i am able to see the output

Comment: http://localhost:8088/DemoJscript/index.html ........... I am  to run successfully on this url also.... thanks a lot..

Comment: please state your answer so that i can upvote............ thanks a lot again....

Comment: Thats fine. Cheers!

Comment: You got it :) :) :)